# Graph theory prove a cycle exists

Tags: graph-theory

If I have a graph that contains a cycle with edges $f_1$ and $f_2$, and similarly a cycle that contains edges $f_2$ and $f_3$, how do I go about proving there exists a cycle with edges $f_1$ and $f_3$?

Comment: Try gluing them together.

Comment: But gluing them might have repeated edges/vertices, which is not a cycle.

Comment: Do you need the repeated edges though?

Answer (score 1):

Let $C$ be a cycle containing $f_1$ and $f_2$. There is at least one path which contains $f_3$ and whose endpoints lie on $C$; namely, we get such a path by deleting $f_2$ from a cycle which contains $f_2$ and $f_3.$ If $P$ is minimal among all such paths, then $P$ is a path containing $f_3$ with endpoints on $C$, but no internal vertices of $P$ lie on $C$. The endpoints of $P$ divide $C$ into two paths $Q$ and $R$. If $Q$ is the part of $C$ that contains $f_1$, then $P\cup Q$ is a cycle containing $f_1$ and $f_3$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a maximal path $P$ containing $f_2$ that is included in both of the cycles $C_1,C_2$. If any of the other two given edges are in this path, then we are done. Otherwise take $(C_1-P) \cup (C_2-P)$. I'll leave it to you to show that this is the cycle you are looking for.

---

EDIT: The above reasoning is wrong. My second try goes like this:

Let $G$ be a finite graph. Let $C_1,C_2$ be cycles in $G$. We claim that if $C_1$ contains $f_1,f_2$ as edges and $C_2$ contains $f_2,f_3$ as edges, then $G$ has a cycle $C$ that contains $f_1,f_3$. Suppose $f_1\not\in C_2$ and $f_3\not\in C_1$, for otherwise we could set $C:=C_2$ or $C:=C_1$, respectively.

Consider $C_1$ with an orientation $\stackrel{C_1}{\mapsto}$. This means that we simply order the vertices of $C_1$. This is legal since $C_1$ is a cycle, so that there is no repetition of vertices nor edges. We can do the same for $C_2$. Let $p_-$ be the last common point of $C_1$ and $C_2$ that $C_1$ visits when $f_2\stackrel{C_1}{\mapsto}f_1$ and let $p_+$ be the first common point of $C_1$ and $C_2$ that $C_1$ visits when $f_1\stackrel{C_1}{\mapsto}f_2$. Then $C_1$ and $C_2$ share no common point in that path $P$ in $C_1$ which connects $p_-$ and $p_+$ and contains $f_1$.

We have three possibilities for the position of $f_3$ in $\stackrel{C_2}{\mapsto}$ with respect to $f_2,p_-$ and $p_+$. Either (i) $f_2\stackrel{C_2}{\mapsto} f_3\stackrel{C_2}{\mapsto} p_\pm\stackrel{C_2}{\mapsto} p_\mp\stackrel{C_2}{\mapsto} f_2$, (ii) $f_2\stackrel{C_2}{\mapsto} p_\pm \stackrel{C_2}{\mapsto} p_\mp \stackrel{C_2}{\mapsto} f_3\stackrel{C_2}{\mapsto}f_2$, or (iii) $f_2 \stackrel{C_2}{\mapsto} p_\pm \stackrel{C_2}{\mapsto} f_3 \stackrel{C_2}{\mapsto} p_\mp \stackrel{C_2}{\mapsto} f_2$ ($\mp$ and $\pm$ are due to the possibility that $p_+$ and $p_-$ might be in reverse order with respect to $\stackrel{C_1}{\mapsto}$ and $\stackrel{C_2}{\mapsto}$, wlog we may assume $p_-\stackrel{C_2}{\mapsto}p_+$ also.

It is immediate that (i) and (ii) differ only by orientation. Wlog, suppose (i) holds. Then set $C$ to be $f_2\stackrel{C_2}{\mapsto} f_3\stackrel{C_2}{\mapsto} p_-\stackrel{C_1}{\mapsto}f_1\stackrel{C_1}{\mapsto}p_+\stackrel{C_2}{\mapsto} f_2$.

Finally suppose (iii) holds. Then set $C$ to be $p_+\stackrel{C_1}{\mapsto} f_1 \stackrel{C_1}{\mapsto} p_- \stackrel{-C_2}{\mapsto} f_3 \stackrel{-C_2}{\mapsto} p_+$.

Note: Geometrically the idea is more evident. Try drawing $C_1$ as a circle with $f_2$ at the top and $f_1$ at the bottom. Then draw $C_2$ on $C_1$; as $C_1$ is represented very nicely, $C_2$ will most likely be all wiggly. The main idea is to isolate a $C_2$-free path of $C_1$ including $f_1$ and using it to complete either $C_2$ or some part of $C_2$ to $C$. Actually, I think I found a better way of saying what I say above:

TL;DR: Again assuming $f_1\not\in C_2, f_3\not\in C_1$, let $P$ be a path in $C_1$ containing $f_1$ and whose endpoints $a,b$ are common vertices of $C_1$ and $C_2$. Similarly let $Q$ be the path in $C_2$ containing $f_3$ with endpoints $a,b$. Then it is sufficient to set $C$ to be $P\cup Q$. Then $C$ contains $f_1$ and $f_3$, while it is really a cycle since $P$ is a path of a cycle and $Q$ is a path in another cycle that intersect only at the endpoints of each other by construction.

Comment: Is it obvious here that there will be no edges or repeated vertices along this path?

Comment: You could say that if that were the case then one of the initial cycles have a repetition.

Comment: What if there are multiple intersections of $C_1$ and $C_2$ such that there is no path $P$ but rather just a collection of edges?  I think the argument still works but is a little more nuanced

Comment: Couldn't there be repeated edges if there is a common edge in $C_1-P$ and $C_2-P$?

Comment: In fact I think this solution is incorrect

Comment: ^ I agree. I don't think this is necessarily right.

Comment: Yes I see your point. Let me correct it when I find the time.

Comment: I think this time the proof is correct.